# Take a range slider of min='1' and max= '16' and make it output 1 through 4 four times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, math

I am trying to figure out how to modify the value of an incoming input/range slider that has a min value of 1 and a max value of 16 to output 1-2-3-4 ( then when the range slider gets to value 5 the pattern repeats) 1-2-3-4 ( then when the pattern gets to what otherwise would be value 9 the pattern repeats) 1-2-3-4.... etc. This should also work when moving the range slider backwards.

The reason I want to do this is to create a list of 4 divs of which if the id of the div matches the number of the range slider value that div highlights. The reason I am using the number 16 instead of 4 for my range slider is because I will want another list of four divs in which each only highlights on every '1' of the range slider.

The problem is that if I were to write this program for a div list of 100 writing a switch statement isn't going to cut it. So I'm curious how this could be solved without one in case I want to scale this.

Here's a fiddle with the html/css/js
http://jsfiddle.net/ME8hA/1/

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

    var i;

slider.onchange = function() {
    i = slider.value;

     console.log(typeof i);
    $('.inner-loop').removeClass('inner-loop-selected');

        switch (i) {
            case "5":
                i = "1";
                break;
            case "6":
                i = "2";
                break;
            case "7":
                i = "3";
                break;
            case "8":
                i = "4";
                break;
            case "9":
                i = "1";
                break;
            case "10":
                i = "2";
                break;
            case "11":
                i = "3";
                break;
            case "12":
                i = "4";
                break;
            case "13":
                i = "1";
                break;
            case "14":
                i = "2";
                break;
            case "15":
                i = "3";
                break;
            case "16":
                i = "4";
                break;
          }



    var innerDiv = document.getElementById('inner-' + i);
    console.log(innerDiv.id);
    innerDiv.className +=' inner-loop-selected' ;




};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just use [math!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

```
    i = (parseInt(slider.value, 10) % 4) || 4;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ME8hA/5/)

Comment: For the second line, I'd suggest the change to either:
`i = i ? i : 4`
or better using the OR:
`i = i || 4`

Comment: @TaoistWA No problem. If you have some free time read through the math link, it can come in handy down the road.

Comment: @Hamatti Wow, I must be more tired than I thought I was (it's 2am here). just put it into the first line. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I know the operators, I just can't visualize math well. I intuitively knew it would be something simple too.

Comment: @TaoistWA I know where you're coming from, it took me a long while to understand `mod` enough to think of/use it practically. I'm sure you'll get the hang of it!

Comment: For the ranges in the question, it would be `i = (1+((parseInt(slider.value, 10)-1) % 4) || 4;`the formula in the answer uses zero-based ranges, mapping 0..15 to 0..3.